# Iterative procedure for unit extraction

Tags: regex, clojure

Sometimes there is a range of values followed by a unit of measurement. The input will be a string of text containing digits followed by units to be extracted by a function. Given a string of text that contains a number followed by a unit the following can extract the number and unit as a nested vector:

```
(def aa ["meter" "kilometer"])
(def bb (clojure.string/join "|" aa))
(def cc (str "(\\d+)\\s*(" bb ")")) 
(def dd (re-pattern  cc))

(defn foostring [strings]
     (into [] (map into [] (map (fn [[_ count unit]] {:count count, :unit unit})
     (re-seq dd strings)))))
```

For example let's try the input:

```
(foostring "Today I sprinted 40 meters.")
```

The output will be:

```
[[[:count 40] [:unit meter]]]
```

However I am unable to extract a range of numbers followed by a unit such as the following example:

```
(foostring "Today I sprinted between 80-90 meters.")
```

The function will pick out 90 for count and meter for units. However, I am trying to pick up the range of numbers in front of the unit.

The idea I believe can extract such patterns will look recursively for "near-neighbors." Namely, the function finds units, then looks to the left of the unit for digits. In the process of "looking left" the function searches for possibly a single digit such as the mentioned example, a digit follow by a punctuation, i.e. slash - or a word. Expanding on the last search let me provide an example:

```
(foostring "Today I ran between 80 to 90 meters.")
```

Or, the colloquial

(foostring "There were 80 90 Yeti running through the forest.")

Although the Yeti example is odd, when written, it captures an idea of people's speech being translated to text. An example of when this might happen is in the process of quoting someone for an article.

Comment: Try something like `"(\\d+)\\s*(?:-|to)(\\d+)?(" bb ")"` for this specific problem.

Comment: I just tried that out and got a nil result with the example "... 80-90 meters".

Comment: Forgot the second optional whitespace: `"(\\d+)\\s*(?:-|to)(\\d+)?\\s*(" bb ")"`

Comment: That regex picked up the 80 and 90 when there was a slash between them. But it didn't work when there is a blank space between 80 and 90. Also, it outputs the 80 as count in the function above and 90 as unit. However, I am concerned this regex won't be able to pick up arbitrary numbers followed by a unit. Such as `"I am hungry for 2 3 4 sandwiches for lunch."`

Comment: You're going to have to learn quite a bit more about RegEx (ie. beyond a few simple things) and delve deep into writing some sort of parser if you're trying to look for partial patterns in words and much more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The idea I believe can extract such patterns will look recursively for "near-neighbors."

If you really mean *recursively*, then you've surely left the realm of regular expressions. If you don't get too crazy with your expressions you can use context free EBNF.

```
(require '[instaparse.core :as insta])


(def foostring
  (insta/parser
     "<S> = Expr+
      Expr = <Stuff> Number+ {<[' '] [Preposition] [' ']> Number} <' '> Unit <Stuff>;
      Bleh = #'[a-z A-Z.,]+';
      Stuff = {Bleh}
      Preposition = 'between'|'to'|'-';
      Unit = 'meter'|'kilometer'|'Yeti'|'sandwiches';
      Number = #'[0-9]+'"))
```

If you don't have a set list of units/prepositions, define as e.g. any word.

```
(foostring "Today I sprinted 40 meters while eating 2 3 4 sandwiches, running from 80-90 Yeti.")
=>
([:Expr [:Number "40"] [:Unit "meter"]]
 [:Expr [:Number "2"] [:Number "3"] [:Number "4"] [:Unit "sandwiches"]]
 [:Expr [:Number "80"] [:Number "90"] [:Unit "Yeti"]])
```

Comment: Is there a quick way to make the units not be case sensitive?

Comment: `(def insensitive-foo (comp foostring clojure.string/lower-case))` and define your grammar in lower-case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?i)(?<lowerBound>\d+)(?:\s*(?:-|to)\s*(?<upperBound>\d+))?\s+(?<unit>meters?|kilometers?|...)
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://fiddle.re/k20ff
(Choose Java since Clojure share the same flavor with Java)